# Доступ к элементу по его имени / тегу, C# - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно получить доступ к элементу по строчному представлению его имени. Скажем, в определенную функцию я передаю число, соответствующее номеру этого элемента (на поле, делаю свои крестики-нолики). Как можно достичь такого результата?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(this.Controls["button1"] as Button).Top = 0;
```

Привыкайте пользоваться гуглом!
В данном случае достаточно было погуглить "c# get element by name".

Comment: Спасибо, подошло. Гуглил, но неправильно составил запрос, потому задал сюда.